# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request: ViewDataDictionary is of type but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am working on a Web Application NET6.0 with Individual Account.  After creating the application, I scaffolded the Identity items and selected to override all files.  I also decided to use my existing ApplicationDbContext.  Then, in my ApplicationDbContext.cs, I Created a unique Identity Schema for the default User tables.
Firthermore, I added two additional tables, Contact & InvestorRelations), with their respective ContactViewModel and InvestorRelationsModel to the list and created a View Model for each.  My Override looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");
        builder.Entity<InvestorRelationsModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "InvestorRelations");
        });
        builder.Entity<ContactViewModel>(entity=>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "Contact");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "User");
            entity.Property<string>("FullName").HasMaxLength(200);
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserClaims");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserLogins");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserTokens");
        });

    }
```

I created a new migration and updated the database without errors.  However, when I ran the pplication, and navigated to the Register page, The following error message appeared:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '_200Blue.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type '_200Blue.Models.ContactViewModel'.
```

I am not sure how to fix this error.  I did not modify the Register.cshtml.cs file and only have the one Models/ContactViewModel.cs that I created to save my Web Emails into the Database.

Any assistance or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After searching everywhere without success, I decided to trace my steps from the time that the Web site was working; I discovered that I added a model to the default layout page that was influencing and overwriting the Registry Model.  Once I reengineered the Default Layout template and removed the ContactViewModel from it, then the Register page loaded as required.